# Detect global types in VS Code with raw JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I have two folders with JS sources which export Classes that are available globally and have JSDoc comments. Is it possible to have VS Code recognize these globally without...

- Maintaining seperate TS types
- Explicitly importing / requiring them where used